# Downloading Webpage as is (python 3.x.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to take some links from a text file and just download them onto my computer. However I would like those downloaded pages to be completely the same as it is in browser. These wiki pages I downloaded are not the same, they don't display some of the pictures and it's just text mostly when I open them.

How can I achieve what I want, saw some things with scrapy and beautiful soup however I'm not exp

My code:

```
import urllib.request

links=[]
fr=open('wiki_linkovi','r')
fw1=open('imena_elemenata.txt', 'w')
link=fr.readlines()
j=0

for i in link:
    base='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
    start=i.find(base)+len(base)
    end=i.find('\n',start)
    ime=i[start:end]
    fw1.write(ime+'\n')

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(i) #save starts here-----
    webContent = response.read()
    f = open(ime+'.html', 'wb')

    f.write(webContent)
    f.close

    j=j+1
    print(str(j)+'. link\n')
```

So yeah In short, I'd like to download webpage completely

Comment: The pictures are different files (jpg, png, etc) which are downloaded when you open the page in your browser and rendered in there. To get the images you need first get the page, parse it, get the images urls and download each of them. Depending on the img url in the page you can have relative or full paths (naming domain plus path to the picture).

Comment: Thanks for help, found a way using c# webbrowser control and got satisfying result